# irssi "Terminal doesn't support cursor movement"

Tags: cygwin, irssi

I'm trying to run `irssi` under `cygwin` and it gives me this error:

```
$ irssi
Terminal doesn't support cursor movement
Can't initialize screen handling, quitting.
You can still use the dummy mode with -d parameter
```

It was working like yesterday. I don't know what I did to break it. Tried reinstalling it, didn't help.

Comment: How are you using cygwin?  Are you using `mintty` or the `Cygwin Bash Shell`?  What is your **TERM** environment variable set as?  `echo $TERM` at the prompt

Comment: Using Cygwin Bash Shell

`$ echo $TERM` returns 

`dumb`

Comment: Try using mintty with a **$TERM** value of either `vt100` or `xterm` instead.